# Apache web-server config, what is redirecting me and how can I change it

Tags: apache, configuration, redirect, http-status-code-404

**Background:** I inherited a web server that serves up files from /var/www/html. The server used to serve up files from the following locations:

```
/var/www/html/alpha/index.php
/var/www/html/bravo/index.php
/var/www/html/charlie/index.php
```

You could get to these sites from the web using:

```
http://apples.mysite.edu/alpha
http://apples.mysite.edu/bravo
http://apples.mysite.edu/charlie

http://apples.mysite.edu/drupal    <-- this one was added later by someone else
```

**Problem:** Someone has gone in and added a drupal site directory, now all the other sites are inaccessible (404 not found when I check using HTTPFox) and are being re-directed to the drupal site. That means my alpha,bravo,charlie websites are no longer reachable.

**Question:** How many different ways could someone have messed with the server config to cause this result? I need to check all the different ways so I can 1) fix it, and 2) know what to watch for should someone try this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about a standard apache2 installation, you should check `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` where you define all the sites that your apache is going to serve. Actually you should all the available sites in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and link those enabled in the previous folder, but what is going to consider is the ones at sites-enabled.

I guess whoever messed with the server config has deleted the previous configuration files and override with the drupal one. You can just duplicate the drupal file for all the other sites and you should be fine.

To avoid this kind of problems in the future just keep your root password to those you really trust :)